# How to see the data being sent by Socket IO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, html5-canvas

I am developing a game using SocketIO and NodeJS. However, the game currently sends too much data and I would like to figure out why by checking the data being sent every frame. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up Chrome's inspect element. Go to the network tab. Enter into the filter tab `websocket` and you should see a websocket item in the list. When you click on that you can then see "frames". That'll show you the data that socket.io is sending across websockets.

Answer (score 1):

```
var socket = io();

...

socket.on("channel_data_is_being_sent_on",function(data){
    console.log(data);
})
```

this will log all data being received by the client, from the server, in your console - which you can access in developer tools, generally F12.